# Can you please tell me how to add this Activity?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

Here is a project that I discovered: There is an Acitivity that holds two more Activities. Are these two Activities different? Probably the LessonAcitivity and MainActivity are java class but what kind of Activity is that file that holds them? How to add such Activity? Please advise..

Comment: That's a package/directory not a class file

Comment: It is only a directory called "Activity" (probably should be Activities") and in this directory are LessonActivity and MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

I will take that as how to add a new package.

Right-click on directory/package where you want new package -> New -> Package. And name your package.

Then you can add activities inside your package by Right-click -> New -> Activity -> Type of activity you want.